# How to fix "@material-ui/core" error in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**React Error:** Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core' in 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\inTech'22-Web Development (EDUGEN)\edu-gen\src\components'

**Command:** npm install @material-ui/core, @material-ui/icons

> **Powershell Response:**
> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use
> `--location=global` instead. npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve
> dependency tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: edu-gen@0.1.0 npm
> ERR! Found: react@18.1.0 npm ERR!   react@"^18.1.0" from the root
> project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4 npm ERR!
> @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! npm ERR! See C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full
> report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-12T13_20_25_675Z-debug-0.log

So, how do I install the material UI package?

Comment: Material UI has changed the way you install the package so try to install by the mentioned command - npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: To install the icons use the command - npm install @mui/icons-material

Comment: this is a very common question among developers so, I'm posting it as an answer, you can like & accept my answer. It will be beneficial for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Material UI has changed the way you install the package so, try to
  install it by the command - npm install @mui/material
  @emotion/react @emotion/styled.
- To install MUI icons use the command - npm install @mui/icons-material